# How to provide include directory path in kernel module Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I was learning kernel interrupt using a small demo kernel module
which use these two header include

> asm/exception.h
>    asm/mach/irq.h

My Makefile is

```
ifeq (${KERNELRELEASE},)

    KERNEL_SOURCE := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

    PWD := $(shell pwd)


default:
    make    -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} modules 

clean:
    make    -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} clean



else

obj-m := irq_demo.o

endif
```

The error I am getting

```
irq_demo.c:9:27: fatal error: asm/exception.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm/exception.h>
```

I found  asm/exception.h  in my system in /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic/arch/arm/include/

- **[1]But how to include this path in Makefile**
- **[2]Is /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic/include/asm-generic/ linked with arch/arm/include/asm/ ? if yes , than How ?**

Comment: The headers under `arch/` are *architecture-specific*. If you compile kernel for ARM architecture, directory `arch/arm/include` is included automatically. Looks like you don't compile for ARM, or `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic` is not your kernel build directory. You may find current kernel directory with `ls -l /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build`.

Answer (score 0):

First try 
adding ARCH=arm after make
i.e.

```
make ARCH=arm -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} modules
```

============================= OR =============================

Can you try adding line before make

```
CARGS = -I /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/arch/arm/include/
make  $(CARGS) -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} modules
```